# Pigeonhole principle problem - avoiding a sum in consecutive sets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

We have 48 golf balls and 30 golf holes, the holes are labeled from 1 to 30. Prove whether or not it is possible to distribute these balls into the holes while satisfying the following conditions:

1.) There must be at least one ball in each hole.

2.) The sum of balls in any number of consecutive holes cannot be 11 nor 18. (So if the fourth hole had 5 balls, fifth hole 3 balls, and sixth hole 3 balls, this would not satisfy the rule.)

I tried many different approaches (and I think that it is not possible to distribute the balls that way). First, I realized that I only need to distribute 18 balls as the 30 mandatory balls are already determined to be in the their respective holes. If I distributed 18 balls each into a different hole, at least 12 of the 30 holes would only have one ball inside. That means that in any case, there will be at least 12 holes with one ball only. But this is where I got stuck. I am not asking you to solve this problem, but I think I need a nudge towards the right way.

Comment: is it possible to turn this into a linear programming or integer programming problem and then study the feasible region ? The result will become the proof

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh I am not really sure about that to be honest.

Comment: @ampersander the question does not make sense. if "There must be at least one ball in each hole" and "any number of consecutive holes cannot be 11 nor 18" , how will you satisfy both of them ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur Why does it not make sense? It means that if you took any consecutive holes and counted the balls in them, you must not have 11 balls, and you must not have 18 balls.

Comment: I think that it is a good observation that there are really only 18 balls to distribute. Note that this further implies that at least 12 holes have only one ball in them. This makes it quite difficult to avoid summing to 11. I would examine the maximum number of ones you can have consecutively (it is less than 11, of course). I think this might eventually force a contradiction where consecutive holes are forced to sum to 18. These are just my thoughts though; I don't know that they will lead to a solution.

Comment: @ampersander you can see it  here https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mmv/papers/yury-KR96.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $x_k$ be the sum of the number of balls in the first $k$ holes.  Since at least one ball is placed in each hole, $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{30})$ is a strictly increasing sequence satisfying
$$1 \leq x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \cdots < x_{30} = 48$$
Let $y_k$ be the sequence defined by $y_k = x_k + 11$.  Notice that $(y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_{30})$ is also a strictly increasing sequence.  Moreover,
$$12 \leq y_1 < y_2 < y_3 < \cdots < y_{30} = 59$$

Comment: I am not entirely sure I follow where this goes. Why would we choose 11? Why not 18?

Comment: The union of the sequences $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{30})$ and $(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_{30})$ is a set of positive integers which are at most $59$.  There are $60$ such integers, so they cannot all be distinct.  Thus, there exists some $i, j$ with $i > j$ such that $x_i = y_j$.  That means that the sum of the number of balls placed in holes $(x_{j + 1}, x_{j + 2}, \ldots, x_i)$ is $11$.  If we instead add $18$ to each entry in the sequence $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{30})$, we would have $60$ integers less than or equal to $66$, so they could all be distinct.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see now: There are 30 different possible numbers between under 48, and 30 different numbers between under 59. That means that some of those numbers must be equal and therefore, in the original sequence, there is an $x_i$ that is $x_j+11$. Therefore we did not even need the condition about not being able to ahve 18 balls in a row, the rule about 11 of them automatically means that the problem is impossible.

Comment: That is correct.